# VB.net loop through resources and input into Bitmap

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, resources, embedded-resource

Hey all I am trying to find a way to loop through my resources and find only ones that have "GAME" in the title.

I am able to do that just fine using this code:

```
Dim ResourceSet As Resources.ResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)

For Each Dict As DictionaryEntry In ResourceSet.OfType(Of Object)()
    If TypeOf (Dict.Value) Is Drawing.Image Then
        If InStr(Dict.Key, "GAME") <> 0 Then
            Dim newPictureBox As New Button
            Dim s As Stream = Me.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(Dict.Key)
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(s)
            newPictureBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(Dict.Value)
            newPictureBox.Tag = Dict.Value
            newPictureBox.Name = "img_" & Dict.Value
            newPictureBox.Width = bmp.Width.ToString()
            newPictureBox.Height = bmp.Height.ToString()

            FlowLayoutPanelNES.Controls.Add(newPictureBox)
            AddHandler newPictureBox.Click, AddressOf newPictureBox_Click

            bmp.Dispose()
        End If
    End If
Next
```

But once i try to place that resource image into a bitmap it gives the error:

```
Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'.
```

on the line:

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(s)
```

What would i be missing in order to load it into a bitmap and also the BackgroundImage of the button?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(CType(Dict.Value, Bitmap).Width, CType(Dict.Value, Bitmap).Height, Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)

bmp = CType(Dict.Value, Bitmap)
```

valter

Comment: Doesnt seemt to work since i get the error **Parameter is not valid.** which is **System.ArgumentException occurred HResult=-2147024809 Message=Parameter is not valid. Source=System.Drawing StackTrace: at System.Drawing.TextureBrush..ctor(Image image, WrapMode wrapMode)
  InnerException:**